# React Proxy to Express API not Successfully Updating DB While Postman Works

Tags: reactjs, express, postman

Interesting issue. So I have a react application that is using a proxy to make requests with an express server that I built. Now I tested the server with Postman and for one. The only request type that works is `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Now when I make a request from the client using that header I get back a response from the server but it doesn't actually mutate anything in the database. These are for update routes. What is weird is that it works in postman.

Anyone have any ideas why it isn't working. I tried removing `helmet` because I know it adds headers that might include tighter security but even that didn't help. Sorry, the project isn't up anywhere to poke around on.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was passing an object to Axios but I was supposed to be passing a query string.